# Unity physic collider not accurate?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

In the scene, I placed two 1 unit size cubes (with same size collider) on 0,0.5,0 and 1,0.5,1.

[image]

The odd is that when I push one of them, let say to the red arrow, sometime it touch the other block some time it do not. 
I tested multiple times, results are unpredictable.

What is the cause? Float point precision?

How can I avoid?

Comment: With your setup, the planes of the geometry are practically overlapping which sounds to me like it would result in undefined/unpredictable behavior. I'm not sure if you can "prevent" this, but at the same time, I would call this a very contrived/unrealistic scenario.

Comment: If you want to avoid this behaviour, you could make the colliders a *tiny* bit smaller than the cubes (I assume you want them to move past each other).

Comment: @Charleh this could solve the moving problem, but also leave a small gag which will cause unexpected results testing ray cast.

Comment: move the cubes without rigibody seem working.

Comment: Of course if physics behaviours are not needed, remove the rigidbody. There will be no collisions between these cubes anymore. Otherwise, It seems difficult to avoid this effect.